# Required attribute is not working Djnago Template

Tags: html, django

Here, I am trying to build a quiz website. I want, all answers must be submitted. But the required attribute is not working.

```
    <section class="allquiz">
<div class="sectionarea">
    <form action= '' method = "POST" >
        {% for question in questions %}       
    <div class = 'question'>Q{{ question.question_name }} </div><br>
    <div id= "choices" class='select' required>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="A{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_a}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="B{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_b}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="C{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_c}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="D{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_d}}<br>
        
    </div>
    <br> 
        {% endfor %}
    <div style="text-align:center"> <input style="padding: 10px 35px;font-size:120%;cursor: pointer;" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have got the solution. I have to give a required attribute in any input section.

```
    <section class="allquiz">
<div class="sectionarea">
    <form action= '' method = "POST" >
        {% for question in questions %}       
    <div class = 'question'>Q{{ question.question_name }} </div><br>
    <div id= "choices" class='select'>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="A{{question.pk}}" required>{{question.option_a}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="B{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_b}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="C{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_c}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="D{{question.pk}}">{{question.option_d}}<br>
        
    </div>
    <br> 
        {% endfor %}
    <div style="text-align:center"> <input style="padding: 10px 35px;font-size:120%;cursor: pointer;" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>
```

In all input required attribute can be used. But that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the required attribute on every input element, not on the div

```
  <section class="allquiz">
<div class="sectionarea">
    <form action= '' method = "POST" >
        {% for question in questions %}       
    <div class = 'question'>Q{{ question.question_name }} </div><br>
    <div id= "choices" class='select'>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="A{{question.pk}}" required>{{question.option_a}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="B{{question.pk}}" required>{{question.option_b}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="C{{question.pk}}" required>{{question.option_c}}<br>
        <input type = "radio" name="{{forloop.counter}}" value="D{{question.pk}}" required>{{question.option_d}}<br>
        
    </div>
    <br> 
        {% endfor %}
    <div style="text-align:center"> <input style="padding: 10px 35px;font-size:120%;cursor: pointer;" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>
```